# Swift - Find Difference Between Upcoming Time and Current Time

Tags: swift, time, difference

I have a date/time returning from an API that is formatted in RFC 3339. RFC3399 looks like the following: `"2021-07-24T22:36:39-04:00"`

To be even more clear, it can be generated directly in swift doing something like the following:

```
let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
 
/* 39 minutes and 57 seconds after the 16th hour of December 19th, 1996 with an offset of -08:00 from UTC (Pacific Standard Time) */
let string = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
let date = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string)
```

My question is, how can I find the difference between times stored in RFC 3339 format in  `String` variables.

For example, I have one variable titled `currentTime` that returns the current date/time in RFC 3339 format, and I have data from my API that returns a future time in RFC 3339 format. How can I subtract the time returned in each of these to determine the difference between the two?

Also, the date returned is not a concern to me. Only need to find the difference in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once you have your dates from the strings, you coud do something like this using component:

EDIT, using Alexander suggestion:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timediff = ""
        var body: some View {
    Text(timediff)
        .onAppear {
            let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
            RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
            RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
            
            let string1 = "1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00"
            let date1 = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string1)
            let string2 = "1996-12-19T13:19:27-08:00"
            let date2 = RFC3339DateFormatter.date(from: string2)
            
            if let d1 = date1, let d2 = date2 {
                let result = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: d1, to: d2)
                timediff = result.description
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: The way you're using Calendar almost entirely defeats the purpose of Calendar. The time difference between two `Date`s is just not just a combination of the differences of the individual hours, minutes, etc. of each date. Doing that simple subtraction will completely fail to account for day light savings, timezone changes, and other anomalies. Automatically handling such complex and varied edge cases is the whole point of Date and Calendar. They already have existing APIs between dates; use those.

Comment: Note, my answer is for same time zone. It needs to be adjusted for different time zones.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to take pieces from this to make it work perfectly on my end.